# Killed in one hit with Force Armor?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Why is it that Fallen Maniacs can kill me flat from 23k hp to zero when I have [Energy Armor with Force Armor rune](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/energy-armor) up? Is that even possible or did my Energy Armor decay without me realizing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you didn't let Energy Armor decay, it's likely due to the [Force Armor hotfix](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5825330/Diablo_III_Hotfixes_-_May_Updated_52312-5_23_2012#blo) -

> Amount of damage absorbed from a single attack will now cap at 100% of a player’s maximum Life.

Though this is poorly worded, this basically means that while Force Armor will trigger on any hit larger than 35% of your health pool, it won't absorb more than 100% of your life in damage - for example, with your 23,000 life, if you were to take a hit for 60,000 damage, Force Armor will attempt to reduce it to 35% of your total life - 8,050 damage. However, since it's not able to absorb more than 100% of your life, it can't reduce it below 37,000 total damage, thus killing you in one shot.